# PHP: run "mkdir" and get errno

Tags: php, linux

I need to execute `mkdir` command (e.g. via PHP's `exec` command). How do I access standard error (e.g. `EACCES`, see: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mkdir.html). Suggestions? Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

I added `2>&1` to my command:

```
$command = "sudo mkdir /home/test 2>&1";
$output  = array();
$return  = 0;
exec($command, $output, $return);
```

Without it, I used to get either `0` (success) or `-1` (error). Now, I get a `1` during one of my tests -- and I think it's because the directory I am trying to create already exist. It would seem that `1` maps to `EEXIST`. How do I map the rest of the errno?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably looking for [`proc_open`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php), which gives you the ability to work directly with `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` as PHP streams, meaning you can use the normal file reading and writing functions on them.

Please be sure to read more details about the `proc_` family tree on the [`proc_close`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-close.php) and [`proc_get_status`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-get-status.php) pages.

You might have more luck working with the text of the error as provided to `stderr` instead of working with exit codes.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot.

You want to catch the error of the `mkdir` *function* via `errno`, but your call to PHP's exec() means that you will instead deal with the *exit code* of the *external program* `mkdir`.

It is the difference between:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mkdir.html (which you cite)
  
and
  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/mkdir.html (which you exec)